# How can I unzip my byte array again?

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, zip

I zipped my byte array named `Result` to a `zipped.dat` file.

```
Using zip As Ionic.Zip.ZipFile = New Ionic.Zip.ZipFile
    zip.AddEntry("Result", Result) 
    zip.Save("zipped.dat")
End Using
```

I'd like to open the file at runtime, to get the `zipped.dat` content, to finally get back my `Result` array.

```
'Extract contain to Result array again
Dim Result() as byte = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unzip a file like this, using "zipped.dat" for zipPath and the target folder for extractPath:

```
Imports System.IO.Compression
...
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath)
```

You can extract a single file something like this (untested):

```
Using archive As ZipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath)
  entry = getentry(filename)        
  if entry isnot nothing then entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName))
End Using
```

To extract it to a stream, use:

```
Using archive As ZipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead("c:\tmp\track.zip"),
  entry = archive.GetEntry("track.gdb")
  If entry IsNot Nothing Then
    Using zStream As Stream = entry.Open()
      Dim b As Byte
      b = zStream.ReadByte()
    End Using
  End If
End Using
```

With the stream, you can read it into memory.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i need byte array on runtime.. I don't want extract content to a file..

Comment: I've added this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I little modified xpda's answer. This is working for me now. Thanks to xpda

```
    Dim data As New MemoryStream()
    Dim archive As ZipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead("zipped.dat")
    Dim entry = archive.GetEntry("Result") 
    entry.Open.CopyTo(data)
    Dim Result() As Byte = data.ToArray()
```